# Error when installing php54-xml in Centos 6.4

Tags: php, xml, linux, centos, yum

I'm trying to install `php54-xml` in `Centos 6.4` using yum.

I did `yum install php54-xml` in Console and I get below error:

```
Error: Package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-4.el6.noarch (@base)
           Requires: php-cli >= 5.1.0-1
           Removing: php54-cli-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64 (@php-ius)
               php-cli = 5.4.22-1.ius.el6
           Obsoleted By: php55-cli-5.5.10-1.el6.x86_64 (CentALT)
               Not found
           Available: php-cli-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-cli = 5.3.3-26.el6
           Available: php-cli-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               php-cli = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
           Available: php-cli-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 (CentALT)
               php-cli = 5.3.27-3.el6
           Available: php53u-cli-5.3.27-1.ius.el6.i686 (php-ius)
               php-cli = 5.3.27-1.ius.el6
           Available: php54-cli-5.4.21-1.ius.el6.i686 (php-ius)
               php-cli = 5.4.21-1.ius.el6
           Available: php54-cli-5.4.21-2.ius.el6.i686 (php-ius)
               php-cli = 5.4.21-2.ius.el6
           Available: php54w-cli-5.4.24-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-cli = 5.4.24-1.w6
           Available: php54w-cli-5.4.25-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-cli = 5.4.25-1.w6
           Available: php55w-cli-5.5.8-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-cli = 5.5.8-1.w6
           Available: php55w-cli-5.5.9-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-cli = 5.5.9-1.w6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried installing `php-cli` to resolve the issue then I get below error:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/php.ini from install of php-common-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-common-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/curl.so from install of php-common-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-common-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so from install of php-common-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-common-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/fileinfo.so from install of php-common-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-common-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/fileinfo.so from install of php-common-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-common-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/json.so from install of php-common-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-common-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so from install of php-common-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-common-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/phar.so from install of php-common-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-common-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/phar.so from install of php-common-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-common-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/zip.so from install of php-common-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-common-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so from install of php-common-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-common-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/phar.phar from install of php-cli-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-cli-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-cli-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/php-cgi from install of php-cli-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-cli-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/phpize from install of php-cli-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-cli-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz from install of php-cli-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-cli-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/phpize.1.gz from install of php-cli-5.3.27-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php54-cli-5.4.22-1.ius.el6.x86_64
```

It seems though there is a conflict between `php5.3.x` which is the previous version from what I can see with `php5.4.x`

Is there a way to install `php54-xml` so I can use `dom_import_simplexml` function as I'm getting `undefined` error when I run a PHP script in console?

Comment: You need to settle with either 5.3 or 5.4 as there is no way to keep both versions installed: they share common files which produce conflicts you're seeing on your terminal.

Comment: @SamiLaine how can I remove Php 5.3?

Comment: It seems that you have installed some packages for PHP (and maybe even PHP itself) from a repository php-ius. Is that repository enabled by default (see files in `/etc/yum.repos.d`, they're just text files and easy to interpret)? If not, try to run `yum install` with `--enable-repo='*ius*'` and see if there are less/more conflicts with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have bunch of packages from bunch of repos (php-ius, webtatic) besides normal CentOS repos. Packages from these repos might have different way of integrating its packages into the system. I would suggest to stick to one source - e.g. Red Hat supported Software Collections repository - packages installed from there can live one beside the other, i.e. you can have multiple PHP versions installed in parallel:

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/?search=php

To cleanup your system before installation of packages from Software Collections I would recommend to remove all 3rd party packages. You can display packages you want to remove by:

```
yum list extras --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=base --enablerepo=updates
yum remove <all_the_listed_packages>
```

First command basically lists all packages you have installed from repository other than CentOS's *base* or *updates* repo.